# What makes prim's algorithm avoid cycles in the code in CSLR book?

Tags: algorithm, prims-algorithm

In the CSLR text book 3rd ed, page 634-635, how come the pseudo code of Prim's algorithm creates MST without cycles? What makes Prim's algorithm prevent cycles in the pseudo code?

Suppose the weight of edge (i, g) and (i, h) is 1 respectively. Since it keeping choosing minimum edges, we can choose  (i, g) and this will create a cycle.

[image]

If there is visited[] for node, then it will prevent cycle, but there is no such checking in the textbook pseudo code below.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it's because `Extract-Min(Q)` is an operation like `pop()` where it removes the node from `Q`. I can't say for sure without seeing the definition of `Extract-Min(Q)`, but this is normally what is done for Prim's. See Step 3a on [Wikipedia for Prim's algo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm): "Find and remove a vertex v from Q having the minimum possible value of C[v]" note the find *and remove*. The algo here explicitly checks only neighbors that haven't been visited yet in step 9.

Comment: yes, your right, @alkasm thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Krushkal's algorithm, we select an edge of which both the vertices might be already be visited and added to the tree(s). Hence we check if vertices are already connected and belong to same tree.

However, for Prim's algorithm we always select the new vertices from unvisited array, hence it will never form the loop.

Answer (score 0):

i had this question by myself but i wanna tell the general reason not base on the
code which you are showing in the example .
as far as you know the Prim's algorithm for making the spanning tree works as follow :

it adds an edge and a node to a tree
so let's consume an induction
the induction is this
if we have a tree and we add an external node to this tree
no cycle will be made
or we can say
the the initial tree which is now changed by adding an external node is still a tree
and of course we now that tree's don't have the cycle
the inductions steps are trivial for one node
and for a tree made by K node it is also clear
if you add a node (of course external node) still there is no cycle(think why?)
by this simple proof and by knowing this that in the first step of making spanning tree
by prim's algorithm we have a tree (because one node is tree of course)
so we are adding an external node to a tree so our shape is still a tree of course
and we can say that no cycle is made

Answer (score 0):

The thing that makes Prim's algorithm prevent cycles, is that during the excution of the algorithm, the selected vertices are dequeued. Which makes the assumption you made impossible.

Answer (score 0):

When we apply
`Extract-Min at step 7`, it must remove the visited node from Q, and then at `step 9`, we are checking if the `vertex v` was visited earlier or not.

Answer (score -1):

This is the eager version of Prim's Algorithm, which is very similar to Dijkstra and uses an Indexed Priority Queue during implementation. The statement

> If there is visited[] for node, then it will prevent cycle, but there is no > such checking in the textbook pseudo code below.

is wrong because if you think about it, the check `if V ∈ Q` itself acts as a check to determine whether a vertex is visited or unvisited.